# How to retrieve only filename without greedy extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get from

```
markets-map.es6.js
filename.abc.es6.js
filename.ab.def.es6.js
abc.js
defghi.es6.js
location-map.js
demographics-map.es7.js
demographics-map.tar.bz
demographics-map.tar.zip
demographics-map.tar.ball
```

the following: `markets-map`, `filename.abc`, `filename.ab.def`, `filename.abc`, `abc`, `defghi`, `location-map`, `demographics-map`, `demographics-map` with Regex. Can you help?

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: Are you looking for, everything up to the first dot?  That doesn't always look to be true.  Or strip certain extensions?  Need a little more clarification on what exactly you'd like the output to be based upon rules.

Comment: The output is given in the last lines of my question. Get the first part with dot 
 like .abc, .ab (users' defined string for filename) but don't get the extensions like .tar, .es6, .es7, and of course NO for .js, .bz, .zip, .ball.

YCF_L was able to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is specific so you have one way to solve it, it is to solve it case by case here is a regex you can use :

```
(.*?)(((\.es\d+)?\.js)|(\.tar\.(bz|zip|ball)))
```

So you can take only the first group here is regex demo :

## demo regex

---

```
Input                         Output

markets-map.es6.js        ->  markets-map
filename.abc.es6.js       ->  filename.abc
filename.ab.def.es6.js    ->  filename.ab.def
abc.js                    ->  abc
defghi.es6.js             ->  defghi
location-map.js           ->  location-map
demographics-map.es7.js   ->  demographics-map
demographics-map.tar.bz   ->  demographics-map
demographics-map.tar.zip  ->  demographics-map
demographics-map.tar.ball ->  demographics-map
```